# Sublime Text 2: Multiple line selection, skip one line

Tags: sublimetext2

Lets say I have some lines like this

```
# ----------------------- #
# Test for whitespace error #
# ----------------------- #
```

I would like to select the first and last line by keyboard.

I can place my cursor at the first line, and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> twice - which results in the middle line also gets selected, how can I avoid that?

Comment: I know it's not what you asked for, but... one approach for this example, is to select the first line then press CTRL + d

Comment: And to select the line: `Ctrl+L`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this plugin, but haven't test it: https://github.com/colinta/SublimeMarkAndMove

AFAIK you have to use the mouse in a clean installation of ST. 
You can select one line as usual and then, while holding `Ctrl (or cmd on OS X)` select the other line with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to skip a line while selecting unless you do as @Oskar Hane suggests.
However in this partcular case (when the lines you want to select have unique traits in common (if you can say it like that)) you could just select a part of the topline, enough of it to be only common with the other line say `# ----` and press `ctrl+d` which will enable multi select, then you'll have multiple cursors with which you can select the whole line.

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXuBgSpLpK4) should help you understand the concept if you don't do it allready.

Comment: I do understand the concept, but there are times when I would like to do the other thing - for example skipping an empty line.